# FlashList's rendered size is not usable with View Wrapper

Tags: react-native, flash-list

I am using `FlashList` with a twist, I have a `state` controlling  if the list show or not, I tried several ways and all gives the same result `FlashList's rendered size is not usable. Either the height or width is too small (<2px). Please make sure that the parent view of the list has a valid size. FlashList will match the size of the parent.`

this is my code

```
   <View
          style={{
            minHeight: 9,
            minWidth: 9,
            padding: 9,
          }}
        >
          <FlashList
            keyExtractor={({id}) => id}
            data= cardOpen ? data: []}
            estimatedItemSize={9}
            extraData={cardOpen}
            renderItem={({item}) => (
              <OrderItemComponent item={item} expanded={cardOpen} />
            )}
          />
```

Anyone?